# Getting the position of a checkbox in a listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, onitemclicklistener

I have a lisview where there are three textboxes and one checkbox in each row of it,I used the following code snippet to get the exact position of the checked checkbox and it worked for me well,but now I want to put it not in  `listView.setOnItemClickListener`   because  I want to delete the checked item  by means of a button not by clicking the items or rows of the listview,But I don't know where to put these codes to achieve my goal,I'll appreciate your concern and suggestions in advance.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.ChkOrder);

            int firstPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            for(int i=firstPosition;i<listView.getCount();i++){
            View v=listView.getChildAt(i);
            cbx = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.ChkOrder);
            if(cbx.isChecked()){

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                 "Checked position " + goods.get(i), 
                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 checkedItemPosition=i;


           }
        }

     }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be solved by putting it in your preferred button and changing the view to `listview` you have declared in your code:

```
Button Delete=(Button)findViewById(R.id.DeleteButton);
       DeleteGoods.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                /** Getting the position of the currently selected item**/
                //////////////////////////////////
                 CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)listView.findViewById(R.id.ChkOrder);

                    int firstPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                    for(int i=firstPosition;i<listView.getCount();i++){
                    View v1=listView.getChildAt(i);
                    cbx = (CheckBox)v1.findViewById(R.id.ChkOrder);
                    if(cbx.isChecked()){

                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                               //          "Checked position " + goods.get(i), 
                                //          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         checkedItemPosition=i;
                    }
                    }
```